# Extracting values from a messy C# string array by SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to take this kind of String and create a new table with one value per row. The string comes from a C# array that values are essentially comma-separated but the string array includes random comments (e.g. `//AB`)

```
{
//AB               "AB:ABLOC", "AB:ABCOM", "AB:ABSTD_DC", "AB:CMTRT"              //VAF               "VAF:VALAT", "VAF:FCSTATSP", "VAF:STATSP"
}
```

This is the desired output table:

```
 **Column:**    
        AB:ABLOC
        AB:ABCOM
        .
        .
        .
        VAF:STATSP
```

I don't have access to create stored procedures, tables etc, I'm just running my SQL on the client (SQL Server).
Is there any sensible way I can do this?

Comment: you might be able to use the regex function to remove the comments

Comment: What is your input and what is your epxected output ?

Comment: Is there a strong request to do it in SQL? From where do you call the SQL query, interactively or from another programming language? It would be much easier in another programming language.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the desired output table

Comment: I am calling the query from within Spotfire via a database connection.

Comment: I have no idea what Spotfire is. can you manipulate the string before sending it to sql server?

Comment: This would be much easier to do in your application. Ideally RDBMSs should be used only to store and retrieve data. Complex processing and formatting do not belong in SQL code unless there is literally no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need -create tables with `AB` and `VAF` name and some columns- I can suggest you a solution like running this query:

```
DECLARE @ColSptr varchar(3) = '//';
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) = '';
WITH CTE(strTemp) AS(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(@ColSptr, @str, 1) + LEN(@ColSptr), LEN(@str))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(strTemp, CHARINDEX(@ColSptr, strTemp, 1) + LEN(@ColSptr), LEN(strTemp))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@ColSptr, strTemp, 1) > 0
), colData AS (
SELECT 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(strTemp, CHARINDEX(' ', strTemp + ' ', 1)))) AS TableName,
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(strTemp + @ColSptr, CHARINDEX(' ', strTemp + ' ', 1), CHARINDEX(@ColSptr, strTemp + @ColSptr, 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', strTemp + ' ', 1)))) AS ColumnNames
FROM 
    CTE
), finalColData AS (
SELECT
    TableName,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(ColumnNames, TableName + ':', ''), '"', '') AS ColumnNames
FROM
    colData
)
SELECT
    @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @Sql <> '' THEN CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ELSE '' END + 
        'CREATE TABLE ' + TableName + '(' + 
        '[' +REPLACE(ColumnNames , ', ', '] [varchar](10), [')  + '] [varchar](10)) ON [PRIMARY]'
FROM
    finalColData;
EXEC(@sql);
```